# angularjs service doesn't see array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, service

I'm trying to build a forum. I have a service and when i do console.log() on the service I see this

```
Constructor {page: "thread", showReplyForm: false, newPosts: Array[0], boardID: null, threadID: "24"}
boardID: null
newPosts: Array[1]
created: 1412040853
id: "56"
message: "test22"
score: 0
```

why is it that on top it says newPosts: array[0]

but when i expand it underneath, it says newPosts: array[1]

Also when I do service.newPosts.length, I get 0. How do I see that 1? I can't paste the rest of the code here because it's too long.

Comment: Because you are trying to access it too early before it had been loaded. When you expand it in the console it refreshes with the original object reference value, that is why you see the behavior.. Are you using $resource ?

Comment: I see. Thats what I thought thanks for your help. And no I am not using $resource. I just checked the value before the ajax request finished loading

Comment: What issue you have?